# Keep video controls 3 seconds after hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

So video controls appear only when hovering on this video, and they disappear after three seconds when the cursor is out of the area. This is the desired behaviour, however it happens only when the video is on the beginning… If I hover while the video is playing, they disappear right away. Is there a way around this perhaps? Here's a pen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJpjJQ?editors=1111

```
$('#video').hover(function () {
  if (this.hasAttribute("controls")) {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
    that.removeAttribute("controls")
    }, 3000)
  } else {
    this.setAttribute("controls", "controls")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKBYKM?editors=1111) but unfortunately this only works for webkit browsers.

The trick is the

```
::-webkit-media-controls-panel
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to do it on mozilla for example.

Comment: this is great, no cross-browser solution I guess